# Bug parsing text to a calendar date

Tags: java, calendar

I've read through a lot of past posts and it appears I'm doing everything correctly, but the calendar is parsing the string incorrectly for some reason. Essentially I'm taking an inputted date and parsing it to a calendar date. The println statements are for the sake of bug testing.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY");
Calendar wholeDate = new GregorianCalendar();

System.out.println(txtMmddyyyy.getText());
System.out.println(wholeDate.MONTH + " " + wholeDate.DAY_OF_MONTH + " " + wholeDate.YEAR);

try {
    wholeDate.setTime(sdf.parse(txtMmddyyyy.getText()));
} catch (ParseException e3) {
    System.out.println("Failure");
    e3.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(wholeDate.MONTH + " " + wholeDate.DAY_OF_MONTH + " " + wholeDate.YEAR);
```

When I input "05-15-2017"

-The first print statement returns "05-15-17"

-The second print statement returns "2 5 1"

-The third print statement returns "2 5 1"

I'm rather confused and am wondering if anyone knows what may be going on. Thanks.

Comment: You're confusing the constants `MONTH` etc. with how they're used; you think it's the month, but it's just a constant that's used to *retrieve* the month. Look at the Javadocs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Calendar month start at 0 you are going to get the previous month

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Calendar wholeDate = new GregorianCalendar();

System.out.println(txtMmddyyyy.getText());
System.out.println(wholeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + wholeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + wholeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));

try {
    wholeDate.setTime(sdf.parse(txtMmddyyyy.getText()));
} catch (ParseException e3) {
    System.out.println("Failure");
    e3.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(wholeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + wholeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + wholeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 2):

`MONTH`, `DAY_OF_MONTH` and `YEAR` are constants, they don't reflect the state of the `Calendar` but provide you a means to interact with it.  I would highly recommend that you take the time to read through the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to better understand what those fields do and how to use them.

But, given the fact that `Calendar` is effectively deprecated, I'd strongly recommend you spend your time, instead, investing in learning the newer date/time classes - see [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) for more details